# How can I dynamically enter the Average range in VBA for Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Im using VBA to enter the average of a range of cells from a separate worksheet. I can enter code that copies a cell into the new worksheet, and also a separate line that enters the Average of a range. However I want it to enter range data dynamically and not a set range. Im unable to get this line to work.

Currently, The first line of my IF statement this finds matching data in the Master sheet, then in the cell offset by 5 columns of the Averages worksheet, enters the cell of the matching line in the Master sheet, offset by 2 columns.

The second line similarly finds the correct cell, and enters the average of D8:H8. (this line works FYI) However, I don't want it to always enter D8:H8 as it will always be moving, I want it to enter the Average of current rownumber, column 4 to column 8.

The third line is my attempt, however this is wrong and doesn't work. Ive tried various variations of this line but still doesn't work.

Would anybody understand how to enter the data for this?

````
ImportNumRows = Range("A6", Range("A6").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
 ExportNumRows = Range("A18", Range("A18").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
 
 'Dim counter As Integer
 
 
'Start of loop
 For counter = 6 To 5 + ImportNumRows
 Set rng = Worksheets("Averages").Cells(counter, 1)
 Set rng2 = Worksheets("Master").Columns("A:A").Find(What:=rng.Value, MatchCase:=True)
   If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
    rownumber = rng2.Row
    
    rng.Offset(0, 5) = Worksheets("Master").Cells(rownumber, 2).Value
    rng.Offset(0, 6) = WorksheetFunction.Average(Worksheets("Master").Range("D8:H8"))
    rng.Offset(0, 7) = WorksheetFunction.Average(Worksheets("Master").Range(rownumber, 4:rownumber, 8))
    
    Else
    End If
    
'End of loop
Next counter```
````

Comment: Ignore the 'Dim counter As Integer' line as this was from something that has since been deleted.

Comment: You can edit and delete the line instead of telling us to ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Worksheets("Master").Range(rownumber, 4:rownumber, 8)
```

Try:

```
Worksheets("Master").Range(Cells(rownumber, 4), Cells(rownumber, 8))
```

Edit:

```
Worksheets("Master").Range(Worksheets("Master").Cells(rownumber, 4), Worksheets("Master").Cells(rownumber, 8))
```

or

```
With Worksheets("Master")
    Rng.Offset(0, 7) = WorksheetFunction.Average(.Range(.Cells(rownumber, 4), .Cells(rownumber, 8)))
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, unfortunately this has an error saying run-time error 1004, application-defined, or object-defined error?

Comment: If the code is run while the Master sheet is active, it should work. But I have also updated my answer so it will work no matter which sheet is active.

Comment: Thanks for amending Kevin. That's perfect! Well, the first option workd perfectly. The second option with the With statement has an error stating Unable to get the Average property of the WorksheetFunction class?
But that's OK because the first option works! Thanks very much for your help!